# Need to download .csv file from URL in java, but I am getting .html source instead

Tags: java, html, csv, url, nio

I am writing a program that needs to download a .csv file everytime it is executed in order to keep itself up to date. I am using NIO and the following code to download:

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
rbc.close();
```

The problem is, instead of getting the .csv contents, I get a .csv with the source for the .html page of the URL. If use the URL with a browser, the correct file gets downloaded, but not with NIO. Is there any way to force the program to get the file instead of the html contents?

**EDIT**: Attempt using HttpURLConnection, bur with the same results:

```
public static void downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

        // always check HTTP response code first
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {         
            // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();

            // opens an output stream to save into file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveDir);

            int bytesRead = -1;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
        }
        httpConn.disconnect();
    }
```

(adapted from: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url )

Comment: If the only way to get it is via HTTP, which I assume is the case since you're using a browser, you'll have to use an HTTP client, e.g. HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: I have tried this approach:
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url
before, but with the same results

Comment: That code is much more likely to work.  I'd put your version of it in the question instead of what is there now.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void download()
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();                                                          // Creates a webclient
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);                   // Uses the Event Handler to check whether the download is complete
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);  // Uses the Event Handler to check for progress made
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("URLpath"), @"destinationpath");           // Defines the URL and destination directory for the downloaded file
}
```

try this

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but aren't those for C#?
EDIT: It's in Java, as the tag says

Comment: sorry, did not notice that